# How to query custom ID object in Salesforce and have it match up with UserInfo.getUserId() function result?

Tags: apex, community, lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app

Here's my code:

```
  public static Test__c insertBox(Test__c box, String boxIDString)
    {

        Id boxID = boxIDString;
        loot.Box__c = boxID;
        String boxer = String.valueOf(UserInfo.getUserId());
        String boxQuery = String.valueOf([SELECT Boxer_ID__c from D_Boxer__c WHERE Boxer_ID__c=:boxer]); 
        loot.Box__c = boxQuery; 
        upsert box;
        return box; 
    }
```

Boxer_ID__c is of type **text**, but UserInfo.getUserId() returns type **ID**. We tried casting the UserInfo.getUserId() as type string and we're getting an invalid id () error:

```
19:33:44:011 FATAL_ERROR System.StringException: Invalid id: ()
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error so that the code can work correctly? I cannot figure out how.

Comment: Where are you running this Apex code? You can use an `Id` interchangeably with a string and the casting will be implicit. I.e. `string uId = UserInfo.getUserId();`. The Invalid ID message makes me think you are running in a context without a user.

Answer (score 0):

Box__c appears to be a lookup field. The query returned no values, which you then converted to a string, which resulted in the string value "()". The assignment to the Box__c field is what's actually failing. You should probably try:

```
try {
    loot.Box__c = [SELECT Id from D_Boxer__c WHERE Boxer_ID__c=:UserInfo.getUserId()].Id;
    upsert loot;
} catch(QueryException e) {
    // there was no value returned
} catch(DmlException e) {
    // there was a problem updating the record
}
return box;
```

Comment: Wow @sfdcfox this is impressive, I'll give it a shot first thing in the morning. I was curious though, how do I treat a lookup field like when it comes to assigning it a value through the code?

Comment: @ihoaxed Use the "Id" value of the record you're looking up to. This answer demonstrates one way you'd do this. It's really just as simple as assigning the Id to the field.

Comment: Hi, I did the above code you posted...and now get the following error:

**'FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject' **

What could be wrong?

Comment: @ihoaxed If it's in the try-catch, as I demonstrated, that shouldn't happen. Basically, though, it's not finding any matching record.